# Firebase db architecture

Tags: firebase, database-design, nosql

My app has jobs and users. When users apply to jobs, they become applicants.

Data related to a job application: `resume (string), date (string), jobID (string), userID (string), coverLetter (string), fit(integer), rejected (boolean)`

I want the data to be denormalized to avoid indexing through loads of useless data. So, I plan to:

```
job1: { 
 applicants: { darnell: true}

darnell: { 
  appliedTo: { job1: true }
```

Where do I keep the actual application -- in jobs or users? Or (I don't want to) a third model called 'applications'? How to best organize this model?

- Resume has a 1-to-1 relationship with User
- Cover letter has a 1-to-1 relationship with Job and a many-to-one relationship with User
- UserID with JobID should be a kind of joint-primary-key
- the documents, i.e. resume and cover letter will only be references to files on S3

Comment: What is the relationship of applications to jobs and users? You haven't described how those fit together. Why do you say you don't want a third model?

Comment: Each job has many applications. Each application has a cover letter specific to a job. Each application is for a single user. I thought I shouldn't have a third model because I would have to update the DB in three places, but I suppose I'm not sure where the real disadvantages are. I've currently settled on keeping it all in the user object, indexed by JobID, with a date and cover letter attached to each

Comment: Since users might exist in more than one job, and the application is specific to a job, it might make more sense to keep it in the job. Of course, if you want to load the job's meta data without having to load all the applications, that may be the wrong approach. Understanding the constraints of how data is read is critical for properly structuring NoSQL apps.

Answer (score 3):

Firebase is not the greatest at relational databases (it doesn't have anything like `.populate`).

So, I would say that much of it depends on how you will query your data and if you will want to use Firebase in the long-term (or will eventually switch to something like Mongo).  If you query applications from both the job and applicant side (example: give me all of the applications related to this job -- and -- give me all of the applications associated with this person), then I would create a new model for applications.

If not, just nest it with the parent that makes sense (typically you want to avoid this -- but due to Firebase's lack of good queries, this might be worth doing).

Just some thoughts.